# Is it possible to get O/R Broker to read SQL statements from inside a JAR file?

Tags: scala, jdbc

I've started using Scala and I've been trying O/R Broker for JDBC data access (I need to access multiple types of databases so I can't use Querulous).  O/R Broker reads queries from files.  A normal usage to setup that structure would look something like this:

```
val config = new BrokerConfig(connectionUrl)
FileSystemRegistrant(new java.io.File("/sql")).register(config)
```

However, I'd like to store my SQL statements within my JAR file for deployment purposes (and to keep non-technical end-users out of these files).  Is there a way to get O/R Broker to read the statements from within the JAR file?

Answer (score 1):

If O/R Broker can access files in the CLASSPATH, then it should be possible.  Put the JAR in your CLASSPATH and have O/R Broker find the files in the relative path.

Comment: Isn't it "if O/R Broken can access files in *a JAR*"? (Or rather, what can replace `new File` in this context? I would hope it also takes a stream or whatnot...)

Comment: pst is correct - I'm looking for a way to load files within the archive.  As far as I know, O/R Broker doesn't accept file streams, since it's actually looking for a directory and then opens the files in the background...

Comment: You need to access a resource as a stream, not a File.